# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/zmq.so'

Tags: apache2, 17.10, php

When I execute `php -v` in Ubuntu 17.10, I get an error message:

```
$ php -v

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php/20160303/zmq.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/zmq.so: 
undefined symbol: _zval_get_string_func in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.33-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend 
Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

`locate zmq.so` gives me the following:

```
$ locate zmq.so
/usr/lib/php/20160303/zmq.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5.1.2
```

If `zmq.so` is located on the right directory, why do I keep receiving that  error message?

Comment: Where you previously got `/usr/lib/php/20160303/zmq.so`? Why you do not want to install PHP ZeroMQ from [official Ubuntu package `php-zmq`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=names&keywords=php-zmq)?

Answer (score 0):

The `zmq.so` is from the PECL extension [ZMQ](https://secure.php.net/zmq). As you mentioned it is located there but it's not loading. If you have updated your PHP version recently this could have caused the issue (this could potentially have happened through a distro upgrade as well).

Either way I think your best bet is to try and rebuild the extension with these commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq.git
cd php-zmq
phpize && ./configure
make
sudo make install

# now we tell php to use this extension
echo "extension=zmq.so" >> /etc/php/{version_number}/mods-available/zmq.ini
sudo phpenmod zmq
sudo service apache2 restart #Since you also tagged this with apache2
```

I found this information from the following links:

- https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/issues/147
- https://eole-io.github.io/sandstone-doc/install-zmq-php-linux